# Alternating string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use regular expressions to match against a string that starts with 7 numbers, then has a "K" inbetween it, and then 3 numbers again. For example:
1234567K890.

I currently have `$_a -match '^\d{7}K\d{3}'`. However, this does not work for my purposes. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PS C:\> "1234567K890" -match "\d{7}(k)\d{3}"
```

This `\d{7}` matches 7 digits then `(k)` matches letter k and `\d{3}` matches last three characters.

Comment: You might wanna set those to upper-case D, lower-case matches against any decimal digit.  So something like `"1.1234567K890" -match "\d{7}(k)\d{3}"` would be true. Otherwise looks good.

Comment: '1.12.234567K890` -match strangely it is returning false for me.

Comment: Yeah I gave you the wrong string, sorry bout that.  Edited, try "1.1234567K890".  :)

Comment: Now it makes sense :) But as per OP should \d should solve the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Tested this, works for your example and some others:

```
$string = "1234567K890"
$string -match '^[0-9]{7}(k)[0-9]{3}$'"
```

It matches against exactly 7 numbers, then against K (casing does not matter), then against exactly 3 numbers.  The characters at the beginning and the end of the string restrict against whitespace at the beginning and end of the string -- if you want whitespace to be allowed, you can just remove them.

Here's a [powershell regex reference](http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/qAxK/appendix-b-regular-expression-reference), which may help in the future.